# How to load a webpage offline in android

Tags: android, webview

Im trying to load terms and conditions of an app I am working on in my application. The client has provided me an html file of the terms and condition and I do not have any kind of server access. So technically the app needs to be carry that file with it. I have done web views where online data is shown in web view but I do not have any ice for this situation. I know I am missing a stupid point here. Please help

My layout file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <WebView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any document to be used on the file is generally placed in the assets folder. Refer to [this documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html). Here is a working snippet.

```
try {
            WebView mWebView = null;
            mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
            mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html"); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            this.finish();
        }
```

Comment: [Official docs say:](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/webapps/load-local-content#antipatterns)
> For the same reasons, we recommend against file://android_assets/ and file://android_res/ URLs. The AssetsHandler and ResourcesHandler classes are meant to be drop-in replacements.

Answer (score 3):

Put your html file into your assets folder and load it with

```
WebView wv= (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/yourhtml.html");
```

---

Note.  For 20126 Android Studio.  For a new project, to **create** the "Assets Folder", **right click on "app"** in Projects, and drill down to "new Assets folder", then follow the wizard.  Subsequently you can actually just drop the html (or other) files **in to that folder in the OS**; after a few moments AndroidStudio will recognize the files and show them in the Project panel.

Comment: Official docs go against using `android_asset`